# What is the recommended approach/tool to publish a react component library with image assets?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, rollup, rollupjs

**Background:**
I want to write a React Component Library with image resources in it. I want to make the library easy to use so that people just need to add it to their dependencies and start using without worrying about the file structure of the image assets. I'm thinking about using some bundling tool feature like asset module of webpack or url-loader of webpack/rollup.

**Problem:**
But the problem is there may be some large images that should be loaded lazily.
**If I bundle the library** with lazy-loaded image modules, the users of my library will be forced to serve the images at specific path as I configured the publicPath when bundling the library. I don't want to make my users forced to have some specific settings when serving their app.
**If I don't bundle my library**, however, my users are forced to use a bundling tool that  understand image modules (therefore still need extra bundling tool configuration) which also is not something I want.

What is the most decent solution for that? I know inlining all image assets instead of lazy loading is one but that would affect performance quite a little.

Comment: `create-react-app` understands images by default. IMHO, if your end users use a custom bundler setup in react, then they should be skilled enough to handle your images. On the other hand, you a library consumer should not be concerned with libraries handling - the library should work out of the box. Either go with inline and lazy load the component that imports the image or copy the assets to the bundled output directory.